# Add checkmark image on ItemSelected - ListView - Xamarin Forms

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, expandablelistview, listviewitem

I would like to add a checkmark image when an item is selected .see below

[image]

I tried forcing the IsChecked to true , just to see the img . but nothing seems to work

xaml

```
                <ListView x:Name="EmployeeView" ItemSelected="EmployeeView_ItemTapped"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
           <ViewCell>
          <StackLayout>
       <Image Source="calendar" IsVisible="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
       <Label Text="{Binding name}" />

           </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
```

C#

```
 ObservableCollection<Employee> employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
 public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees { get { return employees; } }

EmployeeView.ItemsSource = employees;

            // ObservableCollection allows items to be added after ItemsSource
            // is set and the UI will react to changes
            employees.Add(new Employee { name = "Rob Finnerty" });
            employees.Add(new Employee { name = "Bill Wrestler" });
            employees.Add(new Employee { name = "Dr. Geri-Beth Hooper" });
            employees.Add(new Employee { name = "Dr. Keith Joyce-Purdy" });
            employees.Add(new Employee { name = "Sheri Spruce" });
            employees.Add(new Employee { name = "Burt Indybrick" , IsChecked=true });




void EmployeeView_ItemTapped(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                var index = (Employee)e.SelectedItem;
                index.IsChecked = true;
            }
```

Comment: why don't you just bind the Image's IsVisible to IsChecked?  The Trigger doesn't seem necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if every image is the same, just hardcode the source instead of binding it.  Instead, bind the `IsVisible` property

```
<Image Source="checkmark.png" IsVisible="{Binding IsChecked}" x:Name="tickimage">
```

then in the handler (be sure your model implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`)

```
void Handle_ItemSelected(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e){

  if (e.SelectedItem != null)
  {
    var index = (ImagesModel)e.SelectedItem;
    index.IsChecked = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: but this image will have to be outside of the list ?

Comment: I have no idea what that means.

Comment: I tried your approach but no luck. the visible is not getting trigger.

Comment: Are you sure source is correct?  “Calendar” with no extension doesn’t look right.

Comment: yes , you can use it with or without the extension. it appear here  employees.Add(new Employee { name = "Burt Indybrick" , IsChecked=true }); but not on the item selected

Comment: does `Employee` implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: you were right the notify property was wrong is working now . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

did your `Employee` class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` like :

```
public class Employee: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool isChecked;

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        set
        {
            if (isChecked != value)
            {
                isChecked = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");

            }
        }
        get
        {
            return isChecked;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks that was the error the notify property wasn't getting called . Thank you very much both of your answers help me a lot .

Answer (score 0):

Please add Trigger also to change Image according to True False Value
Like this

```
<Image
                                    x:Name="starImage"
                                    Aspect="AspectFit"
                                    HeightRequest="24"
                                    HorizontalOptions="End">
                                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="NotificationStarred" />
                                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <Image.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger
                                            Binding="{Binding Path=IsImportant}"
                                            TargetType="Image"
                                            Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="StarSelected.png" />
                                        </DataTrigger>

                                        <DataTrigger
                                            Binding="{Binding Path=IsImportant}"
                                            TargetType="Image"
                                            Value="False">
                                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="StarUnselected.png" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Image.Triggers>
                                </Image>
```